# How can I extract two strings from a string with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a string that contains the following:

```
<form class="form" 
data-action="Create" 
data-entity="Topic" 
data-href="/Admin/Contents/JsonCreate" 
data-rowkey="007H" 
data-partitionkey="0006000" id="form">
```

How can I get the values of data-rowkey and data-partitionkey from this string and put into javascript variables?

Please note my data is not part of a page. This is still data in a string.

Comment: @Anne when you say it "didn't reach the browser" do you just mean it didn't reach the page yet, or that it might be running in some non-browser environment (e.g. node.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let `formstring` be the string containing your form declaration:

```
formstring.match(/data-rowkey=.+?"/i)[0].split('=')[1].replace(/"/g,'');
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery you can always go for

```
var data = $('.form').attr('data-rowkey);
```

Comment: Sorry the data is in a string. I just removed the jQuery tag. The data hasn't got close to the browser yet.

Comment: look at @Kooilnc answer, it should be sufficient

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#form").attr("data-rowkey")
```

Comment: Sorry - I just removed the jquery tag. My data is in a string. There is no browser involved yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = '<form class="form" data-action="Create" 
data-entity="Topic" data-href="/Admin/Contents/JsonCreate" 
data-rowkey="007H" data-partitionkey="0006000" id="form">';

var rowkey = str.match(/data-rowkey=(.+) data-partitionkey=(.+)/)[1];
var partition =str.match(/data-rowkey=(.+) data-partitionkey=(.+) id="form"/)[2];
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BL9uq/1/)**